# Android emulator: Building boot.img from AOSP

Tags: build, android-source, boot

I am trying to build AOSP 4.3 (build: JSR78D; branch: android-4.3_r2) on Debian 7 (amd64). I followed the instructions listed in [Google Android website](https://source.android.com/source/building.html) and finished build steps successfully. At the end, I could test my newly built image with the *Android emulator*.

Now, I have 3 image files in the `out/target/product/generic` directory: `system.img`, `userdata.img`, and `ramdisk.img`. However, `boot.img` is missing. I tried issuing the `make bootimage` command, but it did not help generating the aforesaid file. I expected `Makefile` to automatically build this file for me since it includes `build/core/main.mk` which has `bootimage` as one of its targets.

PS. I have seen posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173628/what-is-boot-img-file-in-android), but it is still not clear to me why `boot.img` is not built automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boot.img contains the kernel. Which is the interface between the OS and the hardware. We don't have hardware in emulator device.(generic).

You want boot.img? build Android for a real device(Ex. Nexus 5)