# Why is there no boot.img after I compile the source code?

Tags: android, android-source

I've built the android source code and everything works well. I started the emulator successfully. But one thing I am confused is that there is no boot.img. I know that the emulator will go to the
 `out/target/product/generic` directory and use the system.img ramdisk.img userdata.img. But I can't find boot.img. I am building android 7.1.2 r3. And when I lunch, I choose the aosp-arm-eng. So this is something new here or for aosp-arm-eng, it doesn't need the boot.img?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android emulator: Building boot.img from AOSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436938/android-emulator-building-boot-img-from-aosp)

Comment: Oh, I see.Thanks. It's because I am building it for an emulator. If I choose real devices when I am lunching. It will give me this system.img.

Comment: What if I want to build aosp-arm-eng for a device? It says we can flash gsi on any android capable device and flash it. But where do I find boot.img then? It is a hikey960 board but I wanted to flash gsi on it.

Comment: @XudongShao can you help me with my question here?